# Am I integrating wrong?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

So for this problem, I set up R, slicing perpendicular to the x-axis so that:

$$\int_0^6\int_0^3 xye^{xy^2/9} \mathrm{dydx}$$

so doing the inside integral first, I use substitution with $u=y^2$ so then $du=2ydy$. Subbing it in, I get  $$\int_0^6\int_0^3 (xy/2y)e^{xu/9} \mathrm{dudx}$$ and this leaves me with $$\int_0^6\int_0^9 (x/2)e^{xu/9} \mathrm{dudx}$$ Since I am integrating with regards to du, I ignore the $x/2$ getting $$\int_0^6[(x/2)(9/x)e^{xu/9}]\mathrm{dx}$$ $$\int_0^6[(9/2)e^{x}]\mathrm{dx}$$ Integral of $e^x$ is just itself so I end up with $$(9/2)e^{6}$$.

But that is not the right answer, but don't know where I integrated wrongly.

Comment: As far as I can tell the mistake you are making is that you are ignoring the lower bound of the integral. Because $\exp(0)=1 \neq 0$ this affects the result. For example the inner integral should be $\frac{9}{2}\exp(x)-\frac{9}{2}$ instead of $\frac{9}{2}\exp(x)$.

Comment: I think that was exactly my mistake, feeling a bit silly now. Thank you very much for pointing it out. @Fishbane